# Does each thread have its own handler in Android?

Tags: android

The main idea of the question is just same as the title.

I'm not sure if the thread has its own handler, or there is only one handler per application and this central handler does all the distributions of works.

Could you please tell me whatthe case is?

Comment: what handler do you mean? `android.os.Handler`?

Comment: @pskink Thanks for comment.  I meant the handler that comes with  looper, thread, message... Are there many kinds of handler, not just one?

Comment: No, the main thread, and LooperThreads do, and also threads that call `Looper.prepare(); Looper.loop();`.